# Highcharts Treemap colstops for color range selection issue

Tags: r, highcharts, treemap

I am working on creation of treemap for cost deviations between any two quarters for various cost centres . For color ranges I am creating colstops on min and max of the cost. the negative values should be displayed in green and positive ones in red. here is code how i am creating colstops.

Since there is no option to show negative values in green automatically, I am manually creating 5 levels in colstops. This works fine when the max/min is within 50k.

I am calculating  max and min from test$value which contains cost for all cost centres. Then i am rounding up the min and max to the nearest 250000 value . in my "result" i am converting  max1-min1 range into a scale of 0-1, res will contain the mid point of scale. Then i am generating colstops values for 5 levels.

```
    max <- max(test$Value, na.rm=T)
    min <- min(test$Value, na.rm=T)


    ## round up the max and min values to nearest 250000##
    RoundUp <- function(from,to) ceiling(from/to)*to
    RoundDown <- function(from,to) floor(from/to)*to

    max1 <- RoundUp(max,250000)
    min1 <- RoundDown(min,250000)

    result=(1-0)/(max1- min1)*(0-max1);
    res=result+1

    colstops<- data.frame(q = c(0.01,res - 0.0001,res,res + 0.0001,1),c = c('#1a9641','#a6d96a','#ffffbf','#fdae61','#d7191c'))
    colstops<<- list.parse2(colstops)
```

Problem occurs when range of the scale goes beyond 100k in either positive and negative side and 0 gets shifted in green or red side.
Please suggest how can i fix this issue?

The treemap image below displays colours accurately for the range from -50k to 50k. But in next image as the range increased above 50 k, 0 has shifted towards negative side in green region.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post live example of your issue? Some working demo like jsFiddle?

Comment: @ Grzegorz: I have uploaded the image of the situations where colours are coming accurately as 0 is in middle but in next image 0 got shifted in negative regions.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński would you know how the legends' scale extremes are set in treemap-highcharts? I think that is where the problem is. The developer is manually setting the color values in the 0-1 scale incorrectly may be.

Comment: I think that you have some problems with calculation of your negative values, when min and max are not in the same distance from 0. You may achieve this distance using Axis.min and Axis.max. You may also change your function a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/yf03h3mt/1/ You may have problem with your calculation because your axis forced you to end on tick. endOnTick: false and startOnTick: false may help you in this case.